# Connecting to sql server from joomla website

Tags: sql-server, database, joomla, phpmyadmin

I am working on a Joomla website which obviously uses the php- mysql (phpmyadmin) as a database.
I have to Fetch some data from sql server database, which is a database of a site
which is built in asp.net.
I have all the databse details, such as username and password of sql server database.
Can I connect to that database by writing a code in my Joomla website?
I have to use the data of a sql server table.
Is it possible to fetch the data? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you had already installed joomla on mysql server, then you cannot connect to the SQL server. But if you want to have a SQL server, you can install joomla on SQL server by following the link below

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/installing-joomla-sql-server

If it is a static table, I would suggest importing the SQL server table to mysql server which will save you lots of effort.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a Joomla component, create a view for displaying that data and in the model you can include the PHP SQL driver and connect remotely to the SQL Server. You also need to grant access to your Joomla website server by IP, and restrict it by IP as well.

Answer (score 0):

if your Os is windows maybe you can hos it on IIS i suggest looking at this link https://docs.joomla.org/Configuring_sqlserver